# create a table for each different array value in specific key

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
[data] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [SUPPLIER_C] => 000620
                [SUPPLIER_NAME] => ASTRA LTD
                [DATE] => 2017-01-29T22:00:00.0000
                [INV_NUM] => AGG-81
                [SERV_CODE] => 0845
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [SUPPLIER_C] => 000620
                [SUPPLIER_NAME] => ASTRA LTD
                [DATE] => 2017-02-21T22:00:00.0000
                [INV_NUM] => AGG-82
                [SERV_CODE] => 0845
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [SUPPLIER_C] => 000620
                [SUPPLIER_NAME] => ASTRA LTD
                [DATE] => 2017-03-27T21:00:00.0000
                [INV_NUM] => AGG-83
                [SERV_CODE] => 0845
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [SUPPLIER_C] => 000620
                [SUPPLIER_NAME] => ASTRA LTD
                [DATE] => 2017-04-23T21:00:00.0000
                [INV_NUM] => 65
                [SERV_CODE] => 0845
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [SUPPLIER_C] => 000620
                [SUPPLIER_NAME] => ASTRA LTD
                [DATE] => 2017-05-25T21:00:00.0000
                [INV_NUM] => 66
                [SERV_CODE] => 0845
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [SUPPLIER_C] => 000620
                [SUPPLIER_NAME] => ASTRA LTD
                [DATE] => 2017-06-25T21:00:00.0000
                [INV_NUM] => 67
                [SERV_CODE] => 0845
            )


        [6] => Array
            (
                [SUPPLIER_C] => 003053
                [SUPPLIER_NAME] => ECOMM TRADE
                [DATE] => 2017-01-31T22:00:00.0000
                [INV_NUM] => 44
                [SERV_CODE] => 0856
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [SUPPLIER_C] => 003053
                [SUPPLIER_NAME] => ECOMM TRADE
                [DATE] => 2017-02-27T22:00:00.0000
                [INV_NUM] => 47
                [SERV_CODE] => 0856
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [SUPPLIER_C] => 003053
                [SUPPLIER_NAME] => ECOMM TRADE
                [DATE] => 2017-03-30T21:00:00.0000
                [INV_NUM] => 7
                [SERV_CODE] => 0856
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [SUPPLIER_C] => 003053
                [SUPPLIER_NAME] => ECOMM TRADE
                [DATE] => 2017-04-29T21:00:00.0000
                [INV_NUM] => 20
                [SERV_CODE] => 0856
            )


        [10] => Array
            (
                [SUPPLIER_C] => 004146
                [SUPPLIER_NAME] => ACTADVICE MANAGEMENT LTD
                [DATE] => 2017-05-27T21:00:00.0000
                [INV_NUM] => 14
                [SERV_CODE] => 9916
            )

        [11] => Array
            (
                [SUPPLIER_C] => 004146
                [SUPPLIER_NAME] => ACTADVICE MANAGEMENT LTD
                [DATE] => 2017-06-25T21:00:00.0000
                [INV_NUM] => 16
                [SERV_CODE] => 9916
            )

        [12] => Array
            (
                [SUPPLIER_C] => 004146
                [SUPPLIER_NAME] => ACTADVICE MANAGEMENT LTD
                [DATE] => 2017-06-25T21:00:00.0000
                [INV_NUM] => 17
                [SERV_CODE] => 9916
            )

    )
```

I am trying to create a loop which will print array data in separate tables, on base on the key **SUPPLIER_C**

So one table will contain data where the key **SUPPLIER_C** is 000620, another table for the data where the key **SUPPLIER_C** is 003053 etc...

My code bellow, does not produce the results that I want:

```
foreach ($suppliers_invoices['data'] as $key=>$invoice) {
.....table code here...
}
```

The code above print a table header and only the first row, and then print again new table, even the key **SUPPLIER_C** is not changed.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Split the array  to some ones having the only key. and build tables for each array

Comment: Any idea how that can be done? Can you post any code snippet?

Comment: Iterate over array and check required key. Add current item to another array defined by the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$invoice_by_supplier = [];
$suppliers = [];

foreach ($suppliers_invoices['data'] as $invoice) {
  $supplier_c = $invoice['SUPPLIER_C'];
  $suppliers[$supplier_c] = $invoice['SUPPLIER_NAME'];
  $invoice_by_supplier[$supplier_c][] = $invoice;
}

foreach ($suppliers as $supplier_c => $supplier_name) {
  ...table head

  foreach ($invoice_by_supplier[$supplier_c] as $invoice) {
    .....table body here...
  }

  .. table foot
}
```